# How to write response in wiremock as a template with list?

Tags: java, json, wiremock

I want to use template response in wiremock and set list as a parameter. How to do that?

I set up wiremock in Java:

```java
wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo("/somePath"))
            .withQueryParam("place.id", equalTo(buildingId))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .withBodyFile("wiremock/response-template.json") //how to set up this file
                .withTransformerParameters(Map.of(
                    "place", "New York",
                    "users", List.of(new User("John", 24), new User("Merry", 31)) //list to insert
                 ))
                .withTransformers("response-template")));
```

How to write file: response-template.json to have result like this:

```json
{
  "place": "New York",
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 24
    },
    {
      "name": "Marry",
      "age": 31
    }
  ]
}
```

I know that it should start like this:

```json
{
  "place": "{{parameters.place}}",
  "users": [
    ???
  ]
}
```

I

Comment: This answer fixed my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76470633/6073148

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use Jackson2 Helper or any other helper that can serialize to jsons.

1. Add [Handlebars jackson2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jknack/handlebars-jackson2) dependency to your project:

- Gradle

```
testImplementation 'com.github.jknack:handlebars-jackson2:4.3.0'
```

- Maven

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jknack/handlebars-jackson2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jknack</groupId>
    <artifactId>handlebars-jackson2</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

2. Register handler with your wiremock instance :

```
WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort()
                .extensions(new ResponseTemplateTransformer(false, "json", Jackson2Helper.INSTANCE)))
```

The name of the helper will be `json` and that is how you will refer to it from your template.

3. In your template use it like :

```
{
  "place": "{{parameters.place}}",
  "users": {{json parameters.users}}
}
```

4. The output is :

```
{
  "place": "New York",
  "users": [{"name":"John","age":24},{"name":"Merry","age":31}]
}
```

Of course you can customize `Jackson2Helper` and create your own instance with own `ObjectMapper` instance - this is useful if you are using `Spring` and want to use same serialization options everywhere.